# Is it possible for child processes in Node.js to preserve colored output?

Tags: node.js

I am writing my first Node.js command line tool using [Liftoff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/liftoff). One of the important steps in my application is to copy some files and folders to the user's cwd. I am using [exeq](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exeq) to accomplish this. It runs a series of commands:

- **`cd app`** - cd to `cwd/app/` where the gulpfile.js and package.json reside
- **`npm install`** - install dependencies
- **`gulp`** - run gulp

Functionally, exeq does exactly what I want it to do. It executes those three commands in sequence and does so successfully. My problem is that exeq does not preserve colored output, so the logs from `npm install` and `gulp` are plain white text, making them very difficult to parse.

My research thus far has not turned up an alternative node package that does the job nor a clear method for preserving colored output with my current setup. I did get a lead from someone that this may be a problem with the environment and that I need a way to tell exeq it's in an environment that supports colored output. Unfortunately, exeq doesn't appear to have any options or arguments, so I have no idea how to go about doing that.

Is this a limitation of node child processes, or is there a way to preserve the colored output?

Comment: It's not quite clear what's happening here. You say the logs are "difficult to parse", does that mean it contains all of the ANSI escape codes for formatting the text? Or are you saying that the text is just plain text and you want whatever programs to keep the ANSI escape codes that would ordinarily be used when run directly from a terminal?

Comment: @mscdex: Sorry about that. What I meant was that the output is plain white text. I edited my question for clarity.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

So [`gulp`](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp) for instance [uses](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/a54996c6a98acc000ebb310f89d7ca4bbacb9371/bin/gulp.js#L6) a module called [`chalk`](https://github.com/chalk/chalk) to log formatted output. `chalk` in turn, [uses](https://github.com/chalk/chalk/blob/922ac4b0aa67c42b7e0e79ca4a5a7c33beb3e858/index.js#L6) a module called [`supports-color`](https://github.com/chalk/supports-color) which does the actual terminal type detection. When `chalk` is `require()`d, it automatically uses `supports-color` to determine how many colors are available.

Ordinarily, `supports-color` will report that no colors are available when the process is executed as a child process with the default `stdio` options, since stdout is *not* a tty in that case, it is a pipe. Fortunately though, `supports-colors` provides a couple of options to override that check:

- `supports-colors` [uses](https://github.com/chalk/supports-color/blob/983dd4eb0bca835fe53cb0f25c0cf14957191128/index.js#L18-L39) a module called [`has-flag`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/has-flag) to look for `process.argv` entries like `--color`, `--colors`, etc. to force basic (16) color support. You can also use `--color=256` to force 256 colors and arguments like `--color=full` to force true color mode (16 million colors). So for instance you'd supposedly call gulp like `gulp --colors` to get basic color output.
- `supports-colors` also [checks](https://github.com/chalk/supports-color/blob/983dd4eb0bca835fe53cb0f25c0cf14957191128/index.js#L68-L70) for an environment variable called `FORCE_COLOR`, which will force basic color support if it is otherwise detected that no colors are supported.

For npm, you can force color output a couple of different ways. Append the [`--color always`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#color) command-line argument or set `NPM_CONFIG_COLOR=always` in the environment (you can do this by setting `env` in the options passed to `child_process.exec()`/`child_process.spawn()`).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was able to solve the issue by changing the commands to `npm install --color always` and `gulp --color`. Everything is colorful once again. :)

Comment: Hi! Maintainer of Chalk here. Alternatively set the env variable `FORCE_COLOR=1`.