# Format output of spawned gulp process like the parent process

Tags: node.js, process, gulp, pipe

Usecase: On large projects it can be nice to separate small projects into folders of their own with their own build process.

The following setup basically works on both windows and mac - I get the output of the child gulp process logged in the console - only problem is that it's not colored like the output of the parent process.

```
var spawnCmd = require('spawn-cmd');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    // Run all the parent projects tasks first
    // ....
    // ....
    // ....

    // When done, cd to child directory
    process.chdir('./some-dir-that-has-a-gulpfile');

    // Run `gulp` in the child directory
    var child = spawnCmd.spawn('gulp', ['default']);

    // And pipe the output to the current process
    child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
});
```

My question is how to display the output of the child gulp process in exactly the same way as the normal gulp process.

Edit: Duplicate of [Is it possible for child processes in Node.js to preserve colored output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31620298/is-it-possible-for-child-processes-in-node-js-to-preserve-colored-output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should inherit the **stdio** of the parent process. This correctly pipes the output to the same output, with colors and all.

Because you are using `gulp`, you should also add the `--color always` flag, in order for gulp to properly detect that you want colors.

```
var spawnCmd = require('spawn-cmd');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    // When done, cd to child directory
    process.chdir('./some-dir-that-has-a-gulpfile');

    // Run `gulp` in the child directory
    var child = spawnCmd.spawn('gulp', ['default', '--color', 'always'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
});
```

Comment: That worked perfectly on both windows and mac. Thanks!